# Trying to move view when keyboard is appear - some bugs

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, nsnotificationcenter, uikeyboard

I'm trying to move my whole view upwards to be able to see what the user is typing in a textfield. However, it works perfectly the first time as I want it to. However, when clicking on return key on the keyboard (to dismiss it), and then clicking on the textfield, I get the keyboard slightly over the textfield and not getting the same results as I do the first time. Why is this?

This is my code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var commentTextField: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    commentTextField.delegate = self

    //Keyboard listeners
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardDidShow, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardDidHide, object: nil)
}

@objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
        if self.view.frame.origin.y == 0 {
            self.view.frame.origin.y -= keyboardSize.height
        }
    }
}

@objc func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
    if self.view.frame.origin.y != 0 {
        self.view.frame.origin.y = 0
    }
}

func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    commentTextField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey
```

with

```
UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey
```

Answer (score 1):

You are miss-calling the Variable.

**UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey**

> The key for an NSValue object containing a CGRect that identifies the
>   starting frame rectangle of the keyboard in screen coordinates. The
>   frame rectangle reflects the current orientation of the device.

**UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey**

> The key for an NSValue object containing a CGRect that identifies the
>   **ending** frame rectangle of the keyboard in screen coordinates. The
>   frame rectangle reflects the current orientation of the device.

**Therefore, what you need is to check the UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey instead of UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey.**

Do the substitution and you may get it solved.